# Windows Forms - using BeginInvoke if form_load event fails

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

Today I've noticed a bug in my code that I thought I got handled a time ago. I'm working on `Windows Forms` application and I use the `form_load` event often. To handle the situation when something went wrong in the `Form_load` event and exception is thrown I use the following code:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogErrorAndShowMessage(ex, Resources.ERROR_LOAD);

    //Otherwise Error : "Cannot call Close() while doing CreateHandle()".
    this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(CloseTheForm));
    LoadForm<Materials>(closeAlreadyOpened : false);
}
```

And this is how I declare the delegate and the method :

```
public delegate void InvokeDelegate();//used if form load fails
private void CloseTheForm()
{
    this.Close();
}
```

It worked fine since today. What happened - in the `Form_load` event I set the `DataSource` for my ComboBoxes and it so happens that an error was thrown from the `SetDataSource` method which end up with the exact same error that I was getting before using `BeginInvoke` - `Cannot call Close() while doing CreateHandle()`.

This is exceptional behavior, if the exception is thrown from somewhere else the code is still working fine, only if it's during setting datasource the I got the error.

Any suggestion what may cause this exceptional behavior and how can I fix it?

P.S

This is how I create new form :

```
protected void LoadForm<T>(ToolStripButton/*ToolStripDropDownButton*/ formButton, 
                           string buttonText, 
                           long? loadEntityId = null, 
                           bool closeAlreadyOpened = true) where T : BaseForm
{
    MainForm parentFrm = GetParentForm();

    if (parentFrm != null)
    {
        if (formButton != null)
        {
            parentFrm.SetForeColor(formButton);
        }

        T openForm = SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance<T>(parentFrm, 
                                                          closeAlreadyOpened);
        openForm.LoadEntityId = loadEntityId;
        openForm.MdiParent = parentFrm;
        openForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        openForm.Show();
        openForm.Activate();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Parent form not found!", "Error", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

maybe as `Hans Passant` offered I should put `try-catch` around the `openForm.Show()` to deal with this problem?

Comment: This is maybe a stupid question, but can you move your code from the Form_Load method to the constructor of the form ? If the form is not shown/showing, you will not encounter handle errors...

Comment: I haven't really thought about this. I'm not sure the constructor is the right place for this. I guess it's possible though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Load event is troublesome like this.  It *normally* fires when the form's Show() method is called.  But it *can* trigger early if the initialization code in the form constructor requires the native window to be created.  Fairly unhealthy since the form object isn't completely initialized yet.  You can always find out what code did that by setting a breakpoint in the Load event handler and looking at the debugger's Call Stack window.

In general you ought to avoid the Load event, it is only required in rare cases where you need to know the actual size of the window.  Everything else belongs in the constructor, just like it does with a regular .NET class.  You'll need to do something about catching and logging the exception, that's best done with a class factory.  A boilerplate factory could look like this:

```
    public static Form1 CreateInstance() {
        try {
            var frm = new Form1();
            frm.Show();
            return frm;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            LogErrorAndShowMessage(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for you to show up. Actually I have such a class, please look at the Edit post and tell do you think this is gonna work.

Comment: Well, clearly you already have a good place to handle exceptions thrown by the constructor.  So just move the code out of the Load event handler into the constructor.